# element data not refreshing

Tags: flutter, navigation

//calling a different class for dialog on submit click it's not updating list data

It's refreshing data but not going to the last opened tab on the second tab I perform this action but on tap, it's going on the first tab.

```
onTap: () {
       setState(() {
         Navigator.pushReplacement(context, 
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => 
          EmployeePersonalDetailsUpdateActivity(_token),));
          widget.listener.onEmployeeFamilyClick(_day, _month, _year, 
          _working);
     });
 Navigator.pop(context,true);
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to change current screen?

Comment: yes, this action performing on dialog class, on tap, it will go back on activity class my issue it's not refreshing list data using widget.listener I calling API.

Comment: got your issue and imo would be easier if you used flutter_bloc to handle this.

Comment: Why you calling `pushReplacement` and then calling `pop` from Navigator?

Comment: @fartem  then what solution i should try

Comment: You should call `pop` from screen which you leave, not from screen, where you open other screen. Try navigate to other screen without calling `setState` and make needed operations there.

Comment: it's not updating list element data

Comment: The best way to solve this is by using State Management: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options . I suggest using Provider out first then learn Bloc afterwards.

Comment: @s.j Can you add screenshots and if possible full code of for the screen?

Answer (score -1):

Your are calling your widget.listener after you navigate, call it before you navigate the route & if you want to pass the api response to the  EmployeePersonalDetailsUpdateActivity widget, you must handle it, and it's your choice when you want to refresh your screen.

```
setState(() {
 widget.listener.onEmployeeFamilyClick(_day,_month,_year,_working);
 Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: 
         (context) => EmployeePersonalDetailsUpdateActivity(_token),));
       });
```

There's another way:

```
widget.listener.onEmployeeFamilyClick(_day,_month,_year,_working).then((value) {
       Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: 
             (context) => EmployeePersonalDetailsUpdateActivity(_token), value));
    });
```

you can navigate your widget and pass the value of the response and show the updated value on the widget.

Comment: I tried both solutions not working from  2nd solution getting an error.

Comment: with navigator how to define a route for the particular tab to be selected from when dialog closed.